# How to Track if Payment is Received with API in Coinbase

Tags: php, bitcoin, coinbase-api, coinbase-php

I am using coinbase api https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php and I successfully created order button but I didn't found anything to confirm or track that I have received payment.

```
<?php
    require_once 'lib/coinbase.php';
    require_once 'config.php';
    $coinbase = Coinbase::withApiKey(Key, Secret);
    echo $coinbase->createButton("Bullion Products", "10.00", "BTC")->embedHtml;
?>
```

With this codes I am able to show Pay with bitcoins its showing correct values but just want to track with API that someone send me bitcoins so I'll do some action according to it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `callback_url` option as described in [the API](https://coinbase.com/api/doc/1.0/buttons/create.html).

Comment: I have given notification url as http://mydummysite.com/Coinbase/callback.php, but unable to read what is being posted. Please let me know if you have parsed the response using PHP

Comment: Do u have any code snipped to get all notifications using PHP?